# When to use Private Sub and when to use Public Sub?

Tags: vba

When to use Private sub and when to use Public Sub

Comment: When you want to use it in more than one form/module, then you make it public.

Comment: and if one module only or form, private sub?

Comment: as a general rule, yes.

Comment: https://exceloffthegrid.com/private-vs-public-in-vba/

Comment: The only time I have ever used Private is when I have had functions with the same name in different modules. Even then it's not necessary, but it means I don't have to qualify the function name with the module name when I reference them.

Answer (score 1):

You also have `Friend` and `Static`. Study the official documentation:

[Sub statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/sub-statement?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-5002361)